# Row outside Range is used as the first entry in the For loop

Tags: excel, vba

My range of interest starts at B2, but the entry in B1 gets grabbed in the For loop.

```vb
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim RangeOfInterest As Range
Set RangeOfInterest = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("B2"), ActiveSheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
...
'More of the same
...

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
...
'More of the same
...
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
i=1
For Each Row in RangeOfInterest.Rows
    If Not IsEmpty(Row.Cells(0).Value) Then
        dict(Row.Cells(0).Value) = OtherRangeOfInterest.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        i = i + 1
    Else: Exit For
    End If
Next Row
```

The first entry of `dict` is the value of B1 and the value of D1 (from another range that started at D2).
The correct ranges do get selected if I select them.
Also, elements of the last row get left out of "dict".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cells()` is 1-based, so:

```
Debug.Print Range("A2:A5").Cells(0) '>> $A$1
Debug.Print Range("A2:A5").Cells(1) '>> $A$2
'...
Debug.Print Range("A2:A5").Cells(6) '>> $A$7

Debug.Print Range("B2:D2").Cells(0) '>> $A$2
```

As you can see it's possible to index outside of the range you're interested in.

In a single-column range you can just loop over the `Cells`

```
    'if both ranges are single-column...
    Dim c As Range, i As Long
    '...
    '...
    For Each c In RangeOfInterest.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
             i = i + 1
             dict(c.Value) = OtherRangeOfInterest.Cells(i).Value
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please flag as "Accepted" so anyone else coming along later with a similar problem can see there's a solution.